# What is the best way to place a SearchBar inside of your NavigationBar?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

What is the best way to place a SearchBar inside of your NavigationBar for an android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to place a SearchBar inside of your NavigationBar?

The `TitleView` could help you display the `SearchBar` in the navigation bar easily.

Check the code:

```
<ContentPage ...>
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <<SearchBar Text="testing for search bar"/>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

**Update:**

Page.xaml

```
<local:CustomPage 
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App19F_5"
    x:Class="App19F_5.Page6">

    ...
</local:CustomPage>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Page6 : CustomPage
{
    ...
}
```

CustomPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage ... x:Class="App19F_5.CustomPage">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <SearchBar />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: There's no need for the `StackLayout` wrapper! **Never** wrap things in something, if it is no for additional modification.

Comment: @y3z1 I tried this solution, but after navigating the SearchBar text disappears. Is there some way to prevent this?

Comment: @TheUP If you want to display the searchBar in the whole application, you could add the code in all pages. But it's not a good idea, try to create a custom `ContentPage` and add the searchBar. Then make all the page classes inherit the custom page class, the searchBar will be available on all pages. I've updated the code, you can refer to it.

Comment: @y3z1 I have a CollectionView that returns items based on the SearchBar's text. When I tap on a CollectionView item it takes me to its Details page and after I return to the page that contains the CollectionView the text in the SearchBar disappears and the view shows all of my items instead of the ones, which meet the SearchBar's text.

Comment: When clicking the back button to the previous page, the state will not be reset. Check the  gif: ![](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/qp/c2xemrg5z57x.gif "")

Comment: @TheUP Hi, any updates? If you are facing some issues while implementing, try to post the particular error with the corresponding codes here. If you solved the issue, please accept the solution as the answer. It'll be beneficial for other community members who have similar questions.

Comment: @y3z1 Hi, I have been busy for a few days and couldn't check stack overflow. The gif you provided is the way I want it to work, after I get some free time I will try to find out why the SearchText is disappearing. Thanks for all of your help!